# Visual studio 2012 web deployment fails silently, did any one has workaround for this issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-deployment

I am using VS 2012 Ultimate and I did web deployment using file system. It say publish success. but when I look the folder where I deployed doesn't have any files in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried going to the settings tab on the publish dialogue box and then changing the configuration to: Release - Any CPU.

I had the same issue as you and changing this fixed it.